Nunito Sans not showing in FireFox
Im having problem with displaying font Nunito Sans in Firefox DEVELOPER Browser v130.0b5 (64)
any idea why Firefox do not show corrent the font weight and how to fix it wihtout change to different font ?
in browser console i have only this warning
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. markup.js:250:53

this is how i see current code snippet



  body{
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    color: #545454;
  }
  p{
    font-weight: 700
  }
  span{
    font-weight: 500
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
</body>
</html>




Does your console give you any errors?

@MrJoky only warnings
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. markup.js:250:53
Swiper Loop Warning: The number of slides is not enough for loop mode, it will be disabled and not function properly. You need to add more slides (or make duplicates) or lower the values of slidesPerView and slidesPerGroup parameters swiper-bundle.min.js:13:4167

I think this does not affect the font loading. I was thinking about an error or warning about content security policies.

But the code snippet you provided works for me. So maybe it has something to do on how you load the js. I asume you put it at the bottom of your body?

@MrJoky for me is not working even on current code snippet, i added screenshot on main topic

So if i delete the font link from head the font changes to a fallback. I think Inter or so. When i put it back in it changes to Nunito. And when i disable the font-family in CSS it takes times new roman as fallback. Try it too and look if you see a difference. Just disable the font-family via Dev-Tool. Nunito looks extremly simililar to Arial or Inter with a small change in the width of each letter. Hard to tell the difference.

I can't  reproduce this error in FF Developer Edition.  Sometimes locally installed versions of a  font-family can cause problems - albeit they shouldn't as long as you dont use any local  src values. Check also your extensions/add-ons and try to disable everthing
